# oxyplot itemssource datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow, oxyplot

Using oxyplot

Is it possible to bind the data from a datatable ?

The code compiles, but still gives an exception:

> ''Oxyplot exception: Could not find property PartValuesId in
>   System.Data.DataRowView."

The current code is :

```
 lineSeries1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

        lineSeries1.DataFieldY = "PartValues";
        lineSeries1.DataFieldX = "PartValuesId";
        grid.Children.Clear();
        MyModel.Series.Add(lineSeries1);
        Myview.Model = MyModel;
        grid.Children.Add(Myview);
        Grid.SetRow(Myview, 1);
```

Datatable looks as follows :

```
PartValuesId  PartIdKey  PartValues
6277           16          10
6273           16          12
6269           16          15
...
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Made It to work like this :

```
   var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 select new {
                       PartValuesId= row.Field<Int32>("PartValuesId"),
                       PartValues= row.Field<string>("PartValues")
                 };
   lineSeries1.ItemsSource = results;
   lineSeries1.DataFieldX = "PartValuesId";
   lineSeries1.DataFieldY = "PartValues";
```